# Modifying JS generated output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the JS to automatically generate a an input box and button for postcode search. The following JS generated the button. However I need to modify the output slightly so that it generates a button wrapped in a specific span:

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Find Address</button>
</span>
```

I cannot include the span directly in the PHP as the JS replaces all the contents of the target div with a input box and button. Here is the JS to generate the button.

```
   var self = this;
    if ($(this.button).length) {
        this.$button = $(this.button).first();
    } else {
        this.$button = $('<button />', {
            html: this.button_label,
            id: this.button_id,
            type: "button"
        })
        .appendTo(this.$context)
        .addClass(this.button_class)
        .attr("onclick", "return false;")
        .submit(function () {
            return false;
        });
    }
    this.$button.click(function () {
        var postcode = self.$input.val();
        self.disableLookup();
        self.clearAll();
        self.lookupPostcode(postcode);
    });
    return this.$button;
};
```

I have tried to modify the final line to the following but it doesn't seem to work

```
return '<span class="input-group-btn">'+this.$button+'</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this...

```
this.$button.wrap($("<span/>", { class: "input-group-btn" }));
```

before you return the button.  It will wrap it in the span as required.

The problem you were having is that you were trying to return a string value concatenated with a jQuery object, and then another string.  That would have turned the jQuery object (your button) into a string that represents an object.

For readability you may want to split it like this...

```
var $span = $("<span/>", { class: "input-group-btn" });
this.$button.wrap($span);
```

It looks a bit friendlier and more understandable, but does the same thing.

Here's the documentation on `wrap()`...

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly.

Comment: No worries - glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it doesn't work", what is happening?

My guess is that you've forgotten the ending carat in the first part of the span code. it should look like this

```
return '<span class="input-group-btn">'+this.$button+'</span>';
```